# How to say that a word is not used with its literal meaning?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I have found the following definition for the verb *to steam*:

> to steam = to move or proceed with energy or force

in the context:

> We steamed south. From the sea we could see the extent of the development on Coconut Island.

As far as I understand, it is not used with its literal meaning.

**Question:** What adjective defines that a word is used not in a literal, indierect meaning?

Comment: not literal = figurative.

Comment: figurative = metaphoric

Comment: @Stephie to be fair, if we want to believe modern dictionaries, now figurative = literal too.

Comment: There's a more relevant definition: "(of a ship or train) travel somewhere under steam power." From the context, it seems like that's the definition that's being used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to your direct question is [*figurative*](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=figurative+definition).

Additionally, I'd like to address your understanding of *steam* in the sentence that you provided. Its **literal meaning** is actually being applied in that sentence; it's just a different meaning than the one you found. The meaning of *steam* in that sentence is "[*verb* 3. (of a ship or train) travel somewhere under steam power."](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=steam+definition) So the sentence "We steamed south" has the meaning, "We traveled south on a steam-powered ship."

Comment: @DenisKulagin You're welcome. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: A not literal use of Steam would be "After I told him he was stupid, he was steaming." Steaming meaning "mad, angry"

Comment: Some native speakers now use *literally* to mean *figuratively*. This is confusing, and what some may consider 'wrong' but such usage exists. As in: *The kids were literally walking on the ceiling*.

Comment: @δοῦλος The _literally_ in that case actually doesn't mean _figuratively_. The sentence as a whole has a figurative meaning, but the function of _literally_ is not to convey the meaning _figuratively_, as omitting it would not remove the figurative connotation. Instead, _literally_ is used here as an intensifier. Their metaphorical "walking on the ceiling"-ness is even greater than what would be implied by the sentence "The kids were walking on the ceiling."

Comment: @R.M. Yes,literally is an intensifier there. But, as such, it carries the opposite meaning of 'literally' as in 'to the letter'. So we have two usages of *literally*, and they have opposite meanings. I guess that's more the point I was trying to make.